# Crashs UWP From Windows Store - Analyse

Tags: crash, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, windows-10, freeze

I have a problem that I've been unable to resolve. I have an application UWP in Microsoft store, and a report generated by the Store has many occurrences of crashes, dumps, etc. The most common are...

> "MISSING_DUMP_80000003_{Appname_VersionofApp_Architecture}!Unknown",
>   "APPLICATION_FAULT_2154c_{MyProjectStartupName}.dll!Unknown" and
>   "FINALIZER_35730_{MyProjectStartupName}.dll!Unknown"

Does anyone know how I can analyze these errors?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post the link to your app so that we can try your app?

Comment: Try to add custom logger to your application. When `UnhandledException` event occurs -> handle it and write to file in app's local storage.  When application is launching -> check file's content, if errors exist -> send it to some system (your email, hockeyapp etc)